# How to get milk from a goat in Raft?

Tags: raft

The [official Raft wiki](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Goats) says that you can capture a goat and put it on your raft...

> "where they become useful as a source of milk if they are fed from a
>   grass plot. "

It does not say exactly *how* you gather the milk from the goat. I get that you use shears on the llamas to get wool, but how do you actually extract milk from the goat?

Comment: @Wrigglenite no offense, I'm curious why you added the game title to the post? I've seen posts in the past where that is discouraged. Is there a best practice to that policy?

Comment: In some cases, the title alone is so broad that it could apply to different games. In order to not cause any problems when the same question is asked about a different game, it's a good idea to add the game to the title in these cases.

Comment: That's what I figured, which is why I used to do it, but it usually got edited out for some reason. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acording to the [Raft Wiki](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Bucket) you use a bucket to extract milk from a goat. This is a bucket's only purpose.  You craft a bucket with three planks, one scrap, and one rope. Happy extracting!

Comment: Hah, there it is. A reference to the bucket on the Goat page would have been nice. Thanks!

Comment: @TimS. I suggested an edit to the Goat page. It's been saved for me, unsure if its visible to others, but if its approved it should help clear up the confusion!

Comment: Cool, thanks! (I don't see it yet, but I can't imagine it would be rejected.)

Comment: The Goat wiki page has been updated with your update.. thanks for that submission! The Raft wiki definitely needs some love, for sure.